# Increasing multiple buttons with click event

Tags: javascript, dom

I try to increase h4 which is count.innerHTML when click to button. There are 3 buttons, how can I manipulate them, and what is wrong with that code?

```
var btnInc = document.querySelectorAll(".inc");
var count = document.querySelectorAll(".count");

var num = 0;

for(var i=0; i<btnInc.length; i++) {
    btnInc[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        count[i].innerHTML=num;
        num++;
    })
}
```

Comment: could you please share HTML as well

Comment: Wrap your code inside for loop in an IIFE and pass the btnInc[i], count[i] and num to that IIFE so that they have different values for different events binded on the elements.